# Implementation for custom image cropping in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I need to implement the custom image cropping instead of using the system cropping (i.e. "com.android.camera.action.CROP"). I need to know the exact position of the cropping bounding box but this information is not retrievable if I choose to use the default cropping. Besides, the bitmap image is down sampled too much by default cropping.

The steps are as following:

1. Create the original size bitmap from source (using uri). The
   original size is about 4000x3000 which is too big.
2. The user defines the crop area to extract the ROI which results in resizing of the original image to fit the ImageView. (size of ImageView is about 700x700)
3. Record the position of the bounding box in the ImageView.
4. Retrieve the cropped area from the original image and create another bitmap for it.
5. Resize the cropped bitmap to fit the imageview size to show it on the screen.

This approach works on my device (ZTE nuoio with Android 4.3) well. However, the app crashes on Samsung S4 with Android 4.4.4 and Note 4 while performing step 1 probably because of the out-of-memory error.

Therefore, I try to do another approach that creates the bitmap which is down sampled from the source image, rather than having the original size bitmap image.

I need to have the information of the exact position of cropped area from the original image. That is the reason why I didn't use default cropping. Could you please help me out with my case either providing

1. the solutions to derive the exact coordinates of the bounding box of the cropped image in the original image as a matrix.
2. how to solve the out-of-memory error in step 1 using the approach I mentioned above.

Or other approach to achieve image cropping with knowing the exact coordinates of cropped area form the original image.

Thank you so much.

Comment: There are [many image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). One may meet your needs, or it may give you ideas of how to address your issues.

Answer (score 0):

For Crop an image and get Coordinates use library Edmodo Croper https://github.com/edmodo/cropper

For Out of memory issue you have to down scale image.